# How can I place several audio tracks in an HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if it is possible to have a video in mp4 without audio, and tracks in mp3, or is there any way to change the language in an mp4 with several audios?

Something like that.

```html
<video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>
     <audio src="/test/audio.mp3" srclang="es" label="Español">
     <audio src="/test/audio1.mp3" srclang="en" label="Ingles">
     <track src="subtitulos.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="es" label="Español">
     <track src="subtitulos1.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="Ingles">
    </video>
```

Comment: I know it's not what you asked, but mp4 supports multiple audio tracks. You could put them in the same video and use [HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) to enable just the one you want playing. **EDIT** I now notice this is not supported in chrome.